# Can Azure functions clone Git repo to a Blob storage?

Tags: python, azure, github, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I've a business requirement of cloning Github repository on every commit to trigger a workflow starting with a logic app first and then triggering an azure function which can clone Github repository to my azure storage blob. I've never seen a use case like this over the internet, someone has any suggestions of what can be done?

Comment: What about mounting a storage account as a file share in a container/vm? Would that help?

Comment: You can use python sdk [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) to download file your Github then upload file to azure blob.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clone Github repository to my azure storage blob, we can use the python sdk [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) to download files from repo then we can upload these files to Azure blob.

For example (I use Azure HTTP trigger function)

1. Install package

```
pip install PyGithub
pip install aiohttp
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

2. Code

```
import azure.functions as func
from github import Github
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
async def upload(data,container_name,blob_name):
        connection_string='<your storage account connection string>'
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        async with blob_service_client:
            container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
            try:
                # Create new Container in the Service
                await container_client.create_container()
            except  Exception as ex:
                logging.info("the container has existed")

            # Get a new BlobClient
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
            await blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob")


async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    g=Github('<your github usename>','<your github password>')
    repo = g.get_user().get_repo('<your repo path>')
    contents = repo.get_contents(path='',ref='master')
    while contents:
      file_content = contents.pop(0)
      if file_content.type == "dir":
          contents.extend(repo.get_contents(file_content.path))
      else:
          logging.info(file_content.path)
          await upload(file_content.decoded_content,container_name=repo.name,blob_name=file_content.path)

    return func.HttpResponse("OK")
```

Comment: Works out of the box, very neat implementation.
I wonder if you have suggestions, if I want to zip another repository using the same function and save it to storage blob in azure?

Comment: @shivambahedia Regarding the issue, you can get the archive link with the method `Repository.get_archive_link`: https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_archive_link. THen download file with the link and upload to blob